# Set tkinter Entry default value

Tags: python, tkinter, default, tkinter-entry

I'm developing a script that will build GUIs automatically after reading a python script.  I'm having problems in getting the Entry objects that I build to accept a default value.

I pass my method a dictionary (arg) which contains a default value and a variable name.

```
def create_entry(self,
                 arg):

    if 'default' in arg.keys():
        var = StringVar(value=arg['default'])
    else:
        var = StringVar()
    box = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=var)
    box.grid(column=1, row=self.num, columnspan=2, sticky=(W, E))
    label= ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=arg['name']).grid(column=0, row=self.num, sticky=E)

    return box, label
```

The thing I can't explain is that a similar method for looking up directories works fine....

```
def create_askdirectory(self,
                        arg):

    if 'default' in arg.keys():
        var = StringVar(value=arg['default'])
    else:
        var = StringVar()
    box = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=var)
    box.grid(column=1, row=self.num, columnspan=2, sticky=(W, E))

    def askdirectory():
        dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if dirname:
            var.set(dirname)

    button = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text='directory', command=askdirectory).grid(column=0, row=self.num)

    return box, button
```

Comment: That whole `if..else` could just be `var = StringVar(value=arg.get('default', ''))`.

Comment: Much neater, thanks, but I still have the same issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ttk widgets are more sensitive to garbage collection than tkinter widgets. Your variables (which you don't actually need) are local variables, so they are getting garbage collected.

The reason that it works in the other code is that the `askdirectory` function is inside the `create_askdirectory` function so it is able to see the local variables.

My advice is to *not* use `StringVar` -- in this case they are completely unnecessary.

```
box = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe)
box.insert(0, arg.get("default", ""))
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks!  Had to chop the first line to 

    box = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe)

Comment: Kudos. I never would have guessed this was related to garbage collection.